# Does $U^c \subseteq B$ implies $B^c \subseteq U$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $U, B$ are both subsets of $X$ and I want to know whether $U^c \subseteq B$ implies $B^c \subseteq U$. It seems that the case is true because I have drawn a few Venn diagrams and it seems to hold but I am not sure if that is the case since I believe there could be some counter-examples. Would anyone give me some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: both are equivalent to $U\cup B=X$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng That seems legit for me, but would you mind to tell me more on how to derive to this union? Thanks!

Comment: Usually when you use Venn diagrams, it suggests what is natural to write in the proof. So that definitely helps.

Comment: oh! thanks friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly: If $x\in B^c$ then $x\notin B$, so $x\notin U^c$, hence $x\in U$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in B^\complement$. I claim that indeed $x \in U$ because

> if $x \notin U$ then $x \in U^\complement \subseteq B$ so $x \in B$ contradicting $x \in B^\complement$.

So the inclusion holds. Alternatively you could use the logical fact

$$p \to q \iff \lnot q \to \lnot p$$ applied to $p:= (x \in B^\complement)$ and $q:= (x \in U)$.